# Can Azure Logic App pull repository from bitbucket?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to pull / clone bitbucket repository within Azure Logic Apps?

I am curious if it is possible to set up some backend tests within Azure Logic Apps. So to pull repo with tests first and then execute them within CLI. I see that there is bitbucket connector in Logic Apps but there is no option to pull the repo. Or should I check some custom connector to run commands from hand like "git clone" etc.  - if yes which one?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Logic Apps is a cloud platform where you can create and run automated workflows with little to no code. By using the visual designer and selecting from prebuilt operations, you can quickly build a workflow that integrates and manages your apps, data, services, and systems.

From: [What is Azure Logic Apps?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview)

The key concepts here are "little to no code" and "prebuilt operations". Building your code with a CLI and running its tests is not something Logic Apps is targeting. It would also make executing Logic Apps a LOT more complex on the Azure end, since it would mean installing any and all frameworks, tools, etc. that are needed for building the code/running the tests.

If you look at Bitbucket actions that are supported, you can kind of make out that they're all API calls.

[image: Bitbucket Logic Apps actions]

What you're looking for is available for free with [GitHub workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows)

> A workflow is a configurable automated process that will run one or more jobs. Workflows are defined by a YAML file checked in to your repository and will run when triggered by an event in your repository, or they can be triggered manually, or at a defined schedule.

or [Azure Pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines).

> Azure Pipelines automatically builds and tests code projects. It supports all major languages and project types and combines continuous integration, continuous delivery, and continuous testing to build, test, and deliver your code to any destination.

Potentially interesting read: [Build Bitbucket Cloud repositories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket).